# xx.attr("display", "block").click(xxx) not working for me

Tags: jquery, attr

```
$("code").attr("display", "block").addClass("block");
```

This code above is adding the class "block", and is ignoring the attr. How to do it then?

Comment: `$("code").css("display", "block").addClass("block");`

Comment: There is no problem in it. See https://jsfiddle.net/7twr0pvu/

Comment: Do you have error in console? What is your browser and it version?

Answer (score 1):

it works for me ,but try changing attr to css like this http://codepen.io/mohamed_sobhy292/pen/dXVxOx?editors=1111

```
$("#one").css("display", "block").addClass("block");
```

Comment: But I want the attribute "display", which isn't working for me :/

Comment: for me it ads the class top ever tag, whether this attribute exists or not.